# Restricting access to a directory to a specific referrer

Tags: .htaccess

I know that there may be similar (but not exactly the same) questions that have been asked but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I have a website: xy.com/public. I have another site called xy.com/private. xy.com/public is available to the general public. However, I do not want the public to have direct access to xy.com/private (i.e. I do not want people to type the URL into their browser and have access to the contents of xy.com/private).

Instead, I would like to be able to provide access to xy.com/private THROUGH xy.com/public. Or, to put it another way, a page in xy.com/public would call a page in xy.com/private and would make its contents available to the person requesting it in this way. I am pretty sure that there must be a way of doing this using .htaccess. I am using apache in a VPS with Centos OS. I have spent many hours trying to find a solution but to no avail. I am guessing that the rewrite engine would be used.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: do you means that you need only to include from private and prevent request all the file in private directly ? or you need to redirect every thing in private to public ? or you meant that you need to show the private/anypage.php but only if requested from puplic directory pages?

Comment: Thank you. I want to be able to show private/anypage.php but only if it is called by public/anypage.php. I want to prevent people who know the URL of private/anypage.php from accessing it directly by typing the URL in their browser. Basically, I want to force everyone using private/anypage.php to do so through the public site.

Comment: so , if some one want to request private/somepage.php it will be public/somepage.php ?

Comment: No. It will be called by clicking on a link to it on a page in public e.g. public/callingpage.php will have a link to private/somepage.php - the important thing is that if people know the URL of private/somepage.php then they cannot type it into their browser and get access. But... they will get access if they call the URL through a special page in public.

Comment: ok i got it, let me try solution and i will be back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the follwoing code inside private .htaccess file so no one could be able to browse any private/file.php or private/image.png (see this line of code RewriteRule .(php|gif|jpg|png)$ - [F] so you can add whatever you want like js or css etc ..
Right now it is for image with extensions jpg,png or gif as well as php files)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?xy.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?xy.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(php|gif|jpg|png)$ - [F]
```

but they can browse only if they press for example link from public or any other directory.

> Note:

If some one try to request private/wrongpage.php it will give error unless you handle it by several ways for example ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/error/page.php

> Update:

If you need all the request come only from Public directory, you can modify the above code with the following but still inside private directory .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?xy.com/public [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?xy.com/public.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(php|gif|jpg|png)$ - [F]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mohammed. It works. I appreciate your efforts very much!